# How can I use Cpanel UAPI output stdclass?

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying to get the bandwidth data of my website. I am using this class to get the data: https://github.com/N1ghteyes/cpanel-UAPI-php-class/blob/master/cpaneluapi.class.php
It works but I don't know how to use the data it gives me.

I use the following php code in order to get the data:

```
    $cPanel = new cpanelAPI('*******', '******', '*****');
$resource = $cPanel->uapi->ResourceUsage->get_usages();
```

And the response I get when I use "var_dump($resource)" is this:

> object(stdClass)#3 (6) { ["metadata"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["transformed"]=> int(1) } ["messages"]=> NULL ["warnings"]=> NULL ["errors"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(1) ["data"]=> array(19) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (6) { ["formatter"]=> string(12) "format_bytes" ["description"]=> string(16) "Disk Kullanımı" ["url"]=> string(20) "diskusage/index.html" ["maximum"]=> NULL ["id"]=> string(10) "disk_usage" ["usage"]=> int(4854559791) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (6) { ["description"]=> string(24) "MySQL® Disk Kullanımı" ["formatter"]=> string(12) "format_bytes" ["url"]=> NULL ["id"]=> string(20) "cachedmysqldiskusage" ["usage"]=> int(71367805) ["maximum"]=> NULL } [2]=> object(stdClass)#6 (6) { ["description"]=> string(16) "Bant Genişliği" ["formatter"]=> string(12) "format_bytes" ["url"]=> string(20) "stats/bandwidth.html" ["id"]=> string(9) "bandwidth" ["usage"]=> string(11) "63120390532" ["maximum"]=> NULL } [3]=> object(stdClass)#7 (6) { ["formatter"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(22) "Eklenti Etki Alanları" ["url"]=> string(16) "addon/index.html" ["maximum"]=> NULL ["id"]=> string(13) "addon_domains" ["usage"]=> int(0) } [4]=> object(stdClass)#8 (6) { ["url"]=> string(20) "subdomain/index.html" ["formatter"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(18) "Alt Etki Alanları" ["maximum"]=> NULL ["usage"]=> int(5) ["id"]=> string(10) "subdomains" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#9 (6) { ["description"]=> string(8) "Rumuzlar" ["formatter"]=> NULL ["url"]=> string(15) "park/index.html" ["maximum"]=> NULL ["id"]=> string(7) "aliases" ["usage"]=> int(0) } [6]=> object(stdClass)#10 (6) { ["description"]=> string(18) "E-posta Hesapları" ["formatter"]=> NULL ["url"]=> string(20) "mail/pops/index.html" ["id"]=> string(14) "email_accounts" ["usage"]=> string(1) "5" ["maximum"]=> NULL } [7]=> object(stdClass)#11 (6) { ["maximum"]=> NULL ["usage"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> string(13) "mailing_lists" ["url"]=> string(15) "mail/lists.html" ["description"]=> string(15) "Posta Listeleri" ["formatter"]=> NULL } [8]=> object(stdClass)#12 (6) { ["maximum"]=> NULL ["usage"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> string(14) "autoresponders" ["url"]=> string(17) "mail/autores.html" ["formatter"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(26) "Otomatik Yanıtlayıcılar" } [9]=> object(stdClass)#13 (6) { ["url"]=> string(14) "mail/fwds.html" ["description"]=> string(11) "İleticiler" ["formatter"]=> NULL ["maximum"]=> NULL ["usage"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> string(10) "forwarders" } [10]=> object(stdClass)#14 (6) { ["url"]=> string(31) "mail/filters/managefilters.html" ["formatter"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(18) "E-posta Filtreleri" ["usage"]=> int(0) ["id"]=> string(13) "email_filters" ["maximum"]=> NULL } [11]=> object(stdClass)#15 (6) { ["url"]=> string(17) "ftp/accounts.html" ["formatter"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(14) "FTP Hesapları" ["maximum"]=> NULL ["usage"]=> string(1) "0" ["id"]=> string(12) "ftp_accounts" } [12]=> object(stdClass)#16 (6) { ["usage"]=> int(9) ["id"]=> string(15) "mysql_databases" ["maximum"]=> NULL ["url"]=> string(14) "sql/index.html" ["description"]=> string(22) "MySQL® Veritabanları" ["formatter"]=> NULL } [13]=> object(stdClass)#17 (6) { ["url"]=> NULL ["formatter"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(15) "CPU Kullanımı" ["maximum"]=> int(100) ["usage"]=> int(5) ["id"]=> string(6) "lvecpu" } [14]=> object(stdClass)#18 (6) { ["url"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(18) "Giriş Süreçleri" ["formatter"]=> NULL ["usage"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> string(5) "lveep" ["maximum"]=> int(200) } [15]=> object(stdClass)#19 (6) { ["url"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(21) "Physical Memory Usage" ["formatter"]=> string(12) "format_bytes" ["usage"]=> int(39809024) ["id"]=> string(9) "lvememphy" ["maximum"]=> int(1572864000) } [16]=> object(stdClass)#20 (6) { ["maximum"]=> int(1024) ["usage"]=> int(0) ["id"]=> string(7) "lveiops" ["url"]=> NULL ["formatter"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(4) "IOPS" } [17]=> object(stdClass)#21 (6) { ["formatter"]=> string(23) "format_bytes_per_second" ["description"]=> string(9) "I/O Usage" ["url"]=> NULL ["maximum"]=> int(3145728) ["id"]=> string(5) "lveio" ["usage"]=> int(3072) } [18]=> object(stdClass)#22 (6) { ["maximum"]=> int(1000) ["id"]=> string(8) "lvenproc" ["usage"]=> int(6) ["description"]=> string(19) "Number of Processes" ["formatter"]=> NULL ["url"]=> NULL } } }

I need to make the data useable.

---

### Found the solution myself :)

```
echo $resource->data[2]->usage;
```